# flagging the text dataset with respect to a particular word in the text in R

Tags: r, text-analysis

I am new to the R, but I have situation where I need to create new variable flag and mark it as 1 with respect to particular word in the text.
Example:dataframe

```
Text                                        flag_USA    flag_Canada
Canada has 1.6% more total area                  0         1
USA has 0.7% more land                           1         0
USA has 4 times more arable land in total        1         0
Canada has 27.5% more forested and wooded land   0         1
USA has 26.9 times more irrigated land           1         0
```

So I want to create a flagvariable where ever there is USA or Canada in a text.
Can you please help me out in getting the code for this.Thanks in advance for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: anything you've already tried yourself? SO is not a code-writing service. Hint: look at `?grepl`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `grepl` function, grepl returns `TRUE` if a pattern is found in a String and `FALSE` if not.

Your Code could look something like this:

```
df$flag_USA    <- grepl("USA",    df$Text)
df$flag_Canada <- grepl("Canada", df$Text)
```

If you really need numbers instead of TRUE/FALSE you could use `as.integer` to convert TRUE/FALSE to 1/0.

Answer (score 1):

We can also extract the words with `regexpr/regmatches` and convert it to binary columns with `binary`.  This will be useful when there are many keywords and don't want to repeatedly do the `grepl`

```
df1[c('flag_USA', 'flag_Canada')] <- table(1:nrow(df1), 
     factor(regmatches(df1$Text, regexpr('USA|Canada', df1$Text)), 
                levels=c('USA', 'Canada')))
df1
#                                             Text flag_USA flag_Canada
#1                Canada has 1.6% more total area        0           1
#2                         USA has 0.7% more land        1           0
#3      USA has 4 times more arable land in total        1           0
#4 Canada has 27.5% more forested and wooded land        0           1
#5         USA has 26.9 times more irrigated land        1           0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect task for applying a dictionary to text using the **quanteda** package.  First you define a dictionary with the patterns (which can be matched using "glob" matches, fixed format, or regular expressions -- see `?dfm` or `?applyDictionary`) and then use this on your texts to create a document-feature matrix using `dfm()` and the `dictionary` argument.

```
> txt <- c("Canada has 1.6% more total area",
+          "USA has 0.7% more land",
+          "USA has 4 times more arable land in total",
+          "Canada has 27.5% more forested and wooded land",
+          "USA has 26.9 times more irrigated land")
> require(quanteda)
> myDictionary <- dictionary(list(flag_USA = "USA", flag_Canada = "Canada"))
> dfm(txt, dictionary = myDictionary)
Creating a dfm from a character vector ...
   ... lowercasing
   ... tokenizing
   ... indexing documents: 5 documents
   ... indexing features: 14 feature types
   ... applying a dictionary consisting of 2 keys
   ... created a 5 x 2 sparse dfm
   ... complete. 
Elapsed time: 0.014 seconds.
Document-feature matrix of: 5 documents, 2 features.
5 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
       features
docs    flag_USA flag_Canada
  text1        0           1
  text2        1           0
  text3        1           0
  text4        0           1
  text5        1           0
```